# Spring form changed value in not getting reflected in ModelAttribute

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc, modelattribute, spring-form

I have the following form

```
<form:form id="form" name="form" target="dummyHiddenForm"  method="post" commandName="myForm" >

            <span class="container">
                <label>TestKey</label>
                <span class="container-right">
                    <form:input path="key" id="key" cssClass="text" maxlength="200" cssStyle="width:60%" disabled="true"/>
                    <input type="button" class="refreshIcon" style="width:auto;" onclick="javascript:refreshKey()" />
                </span>
            </span>

    <span style="width:auto; padding-left: 30%; padding-bottom: 4%; text-align:center; float:right; clear:both;">
        <input type="button" class="button" style="width:auto;" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:submitForm()"/>
    </span> 

</form:form>

<iframe id="dummyHiddenForm" name="dummyHiddenForm" style="display:none;" ></iframe>
```

In GET request for above page containing form I am setting some default value for each variable of object myForm and `key` is set to value `""`. 
and my java script function for refreshKey() is

```
function refreshKey(){
    document.getElementById('key').value = generateKey() ; 
}
```

This method correctly works and onclick sets new key in the input text fields.

on click of submit button I am submitting the form using java script

```
function submitForm(){
        var formVar = document.forms["form"];
        formVar.action = "/test.htm";
        formVar.submit();
}
```

But in my controller I get the same default value `""`  for key irrespective of the the actual value of the input field.

I tried using javascript `alert` and `.value` I can see the changed value but the value does not change in actual DOM (at least when I do inspect element from firefox it still shows `value=""`).

I need to get the changed value when the form is submitted. Any suggestions what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out an workaround. The problem was arising due to disabled property i.e `disabled="true"`. Though java script has acess and can modify the `value` attribute of the input it is not reflected when the spring form is submitted. There was no problem with model attribute binding which I suspected in the begining. Works fine with the disabled attribue turned off.

However if you still want to make your input field uneditable there is another property `readonly` which you can set to true. Change the value with javascript and the value is reflected back in the model attribute on form submit.

```
<form:input path="key" id="key" cssClass="text" maxlength="200" cssStyle="width:60%" readonly="true"/>
```